# Simple Undirected Network in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, networkx

The simplest network graph:

- undirected Network
- edges without attribute.

Such as in Python NetworkX

[image]

But If I want to save this simplest graph in Neo4j,

First, due to Neo4j's relationship is one direction only, I have to create two relationships for each undirected edge here.

Or as some threads suggested that use only ONE "one directional relationship" for each edge, but when query, ignore the direction. (But using this approach, when you visualize the graph, it does not reflect the graph as it should be.) We have to remember "to ignore direction"

Second, even this graph's edge is without relationship attribute, but to save the edge in Neo4j as Neo4j's relationship, due to Neo4j relationship has to have a type, I have to give a dummy relationship attribute.

I am just curious what is the design philosophy and logic behind Neo4j, that Neo4j does not have the simplest graph structure, the undirected network and edge without attribute, built into it directly?

Usually, I would assume a graph database would start with the simplest graph structure.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Questions about the philosophy or reasoning behind the specific design of a DBMS might be better directed to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, or perhaps directed specifically to the neo4j developers, who have slack channels for such questions.

Comment: I also encourage you to ignore direction and just MERGE in your relationships. If you know from the start that direction has no meaning, then it shouldn't be hard to ignore it when it comes to visualization. As for the type of a relationship, a type is not the same as an attribute. Just use a :REL type or similar, and that's it. As for philosophy, Neo4j implements the property graph model, which includes directed edges and allows labeled edges.